# JQuery .click, nor .on("click", ...) working with ASP .NET and twitter-boostrap elements created using a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

I tried wording this question the best I could... I'm sorry if it wasn't clear but here is my issue.

This is my .js file"

```
 $(function()
 {
     $(".dropup").on("click", function(e) { alert(''); });

     $(".chat-friend").click(newChat);
 });


 function newChat()
 {          
    var chatboxExpandedHTML = '<ul id="chatwindow-expanded" class="dropdown-menu">' +
                            '<li><span style="background-color:red"></span></li>' +
                            '<li><b>Bob:</b></li>' +
                            '<li>I like mashed taters.</li>' +
                            '<li><b>You</b></li>' +
                            '<li>I like mashed taters too.</li>' +
                            '<li>And chicken too.</li>' +
                            '<li><b>Bob:</b></li>' +
                            '<li>We can\'t be friends any more.</li>' +
                            '<li><input type="text" class="chatter" placeholder="Type something…"></li>' +
                            '<li class="divider"></li>' +
                          '</ul>';
    var chatboxMiniHTML = '<li class="dropup">' +
                          '<span class="message-box dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><b>Test123</b></span>'
   + chatboxExpandedHTML +
                          '</li>';


    $('#chatbar-center').append(chatboxMiniHTML);
 }
```

here is the view just in case it's needed..

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" ClassName="Octgn.App.c" %>
<link href="../../Content/css/ChatbarStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../../Content/js/chatservice.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="chatbar">
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <ul id="chatbar-left" class="nav pull-left">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-cog icon-white"></i>Settings</a></li>
                        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul id="chatbar-center" class="nav">

                    </ul>
                    <ul id="chatbar-right" class="nav pull-right">
                        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                        <li class="chat-availability"></li>
                        <li class="dropup">
                          <a href="#" id="friends" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Friends(1)</a>
                          <ul id="friendslist" class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#" class="chat-friend">Alice</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="chat-friend">Bob</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                        <li class="notifications">1</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
        <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what works: I click on the element with a .chat-friend class, and the element with the class .message-box appends to #chatbar-center just fine.  No problems there.

I click on the button that it creates, and it creates the dropup with the class .chatwindow-expanded, the element with the input in it, just fine.

It's when the message-box is created that the events don't work. The alert shows up when I click the friends list, but not the message box, even though they are bot in the dropups class.

What am I doing wrong here?  Is it because it's being created in a function and the event is created before the element is created?  is it because the string is using the '+' instead of '\'?  I tried using that but the button wouldn't even show up, and it does with '+'.

My head is pounding because of this.  I've already tried variations of .on("click", ...) and .click(...); I have also tried putting $('input') and $('li'), etc... so many different things.

Comment: Did you check the error console

Comment: I didn't see any errors in the IDE I am using nor any errors in the firefox web console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it because it's being created in a function and the event is created before the element is created?

Yes. Use event delegation to solve this problem

```
 $("#chatbar-center").on("click", '.dropup', function(e) { alert(''); });
 $("#chatbar-center").on('click', ".chat-friend", newChat);
```

This means that all `.dropup` descendants of `#chatbar-center` will be bound to the event (ofcourse `#chatbar-center` needs to exist at the time)